# Looking up a value based on 2 conditions with HLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a pivot table based on a large group of data. I want to filter this data into a simple table to generate a report. I tried HLookup but it fails as I change the settings of the pivot table. so I need to do it with something like;

=if team is EN & its on Afternoon shift then the afternoon shift number is x.

Here is the google sheet link for more illustration: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mk5xhn9Su26ptmRMLINcKxViP2SgkKrjiA9jfy5a9wM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you want every value or only whats specified ?

Comment: Just one formula is enough and i ll understand the rest, thank you so much and merry Christmas for you and your family.

Comment: solution added, Happy holidays Reda

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(L2:L, TRANSPOSE(A1:I11), {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

all in one:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IFNA(VLOOKUP(L2:L9, TRANSPOSE(A1:I11), {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 0));
   QUERY(QUERY(IFNA(VLOOKUP(L2:L9, TRANSPOSE(A1:I11), {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 0)), 
 "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4),sum(Col5),sum(Col6)", 0), "offset 1", 0)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi Dear. can you please explain what this numbers are for? {2,3,4,5,6,7}.

Comment: those are columns coz table on the left got transposed. but in this occasion you can think of it as they are rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE($A$1:$I$11)),"SELECT Col2 where Col1 = '"&$L2&"'",0)
```

what this does is transpose your data to get it in the format you need, you can then specify the column based on the index of your left hand column i.e `Col2 = afternoon`

if you just want it transposed without any sort of querying or filtering you can just do

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(A1:I11))
```

which will give you

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, i ll try to apply this and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hlookup like this:

```
=transpose( {{"Team";A2:A7}, arrayformula( hlookup( if( row( A1:A7)^0*COLUMN(B1:I1)^0=1,B1:I1,""),B1:I7,sequence(counta(A1:A7),1),false))})
```

explanation:

1. {"Team";A2:A7} with transpose will give header:

   ```
   Team    Afternoon   AL  MC  ML  Morning Night
   ```
2. row( A1:A7)^0*COLUMN(B1:I1)^0 with array formula will give

   ```
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   ```
3. if( row(A1:A7)^0 *COLUMN(B1:I1)^0 = 1, B1:I1,"")

   ```
   EN  DE  FR  UK  GE  BR  EG  IL
   EN  DE  FR  UK  GE  BR  EG  IL
   EN  DE  FR  UK  GE  BR  EG  IL
   EN  DE  FR  UK  GE  BR  EG  IL
   EN  DE  FR  UK  GE  BR  EG  IL
   EN  DE  FR  UK  GE  BR  EG  IL
   EN  DE  FR  UK  GE  BR  EG  IL
   ```
4. hlookup( if( row(A1:A7)^0 *COLUMN(B1:I1)^0 = 1, B1:I1,"") , B1:I7, sequence(counta(A1:A7),1),false) with arrayformula will give:

   ```
   EN  DE  FR  UK  GE  BR  EG  IL
   9   5   8   5   5   3   2   2
   1   1   1                   
   2       1   2               
                           1   
   6   6   5   4   4   2   1   1
   15  7   6   5   4   3   2   1
   ```
5. All formula will give (after transpose):

   ```
   Team    Afternoon   AL  MC  ML  Morning Night
   EN      9           1   2       6       1500%
   DE      5           1           6       700%
   FR      8           1   1       5       600%
   UK      5               2       4       500%
   GE      5                       4       400%
   BR      3                       2       300%
   EG      2                   1   1       200%
   IL      2                       1       100%
   ```

But the easy way, just use transpose:

```
=transpose({"team",B1:I1 ;A2:I7})
```